# Eclipse PDE: Programmatically detect opened dialog and close it

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-pde

On Eclipse Luna, I select a server and click the Start button on Servers view, then the server (for example Tomcat8) will get started. If something is wrong during the start-up process, a dialog will be populated to display the error messages (for example time-out). The dialog is modeless in this test case.

Now I need to start the server programmatically from a plugin. In case that errors occur, how could I programmatically detect that a dialog has been opened and how to close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Display.addFilter` method to listen for all `SWT.Activate` events which will tell you about all Shells (and other things) being activated. You can then detect the shells you want to close.

Something like:

```java
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.Activate, new Listener()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final Event event)
    {
      // Is this a Shell being activated?

      if (event.widget instanceof Shell)
       {
         final Shell shell = (Shell)event.widget;

         // Look at the shell title to see if it is the one we want

         if ("About".equals(shell.getText()))
          {
            // Close the shell after it has finished initializing

            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
             {
               @Override
               public void run()
               {
                 shell.close();
               }
             });
          }
       }
    }
  });
```

which closes a dialog called 'About'.

In more recent versions of Java the above can be simplified to:

```java
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.Activate, event ->
  {
    // Is this a Shell being activated?

    if (event.widget instanceof Shell shell)
     {
       // Look at the shell title to see if it is the one we want

       if ("About".equals(shell.getText()))
        {
          // Close the shell after it has finished initializing

          Display.getDefault().asyncExec(shell::close);
        }
     }
  });
```

This uses Java 8 lambdas and method references and Java 16 instanceof type patterns.